# Obj-C How to call a method with return?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

I have a method with a return value that I want to call from my MainviewController.m. Also, I must pass a value (float) to the method when calling it.
But I'm having trouble with that, I tried to debug and add some breakpoints and NSLog in the method but it appears that the method is not being called, since the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint and doesn't print the NSLog. (the final print (calculatorScreen.text...) just print (null))

MainViewController.m

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
NSNumber *convertedNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] init];
NSString *nf = [convertedNumber customFormatNumber:currentNumber];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nf]; // it's printing (null) :(
```

NSNumber+FormatNumber.h

```
@interface NSNumber (FormatNumber)
-(NSString *) customFormatNumber:(float)n1;
```

NSNumber+FormatNumber.m

```
-(NSString *) customFormatNumber:(float)n1
{
    NSLog(@" %f" ,n1); // for debug and a breakpoint here
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
        NSString *nf = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:n1]];
    NSLog(@"Class %@" ,nf); // for debug
    return nf;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing `[formatter release]` and hence there is a memory leak.

Comment: You might want to change last line to `calculatorScreen.text = nf`. No need to wrap one string into another.

Comment: have you tried logging `currentNumber`? and why are you creating `customFormatNumber:` as an instance method? if its not dependent on any instance variables I would make it a class method.

Comment: @bioffe `[formatter release]` should go before the return?

Comment: @KDaker yes, it's ok when logging `currentNumber`

Comment: @bioffe If I change last line to `calculatorScreen.text = nf` I get `Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UILabel *__strong' from 'NSString *__strong'`

Comment: I wouldn't create such extension. Every time you need to convert a number, you alloc/dealloc `NSNumberFormatter`. It's a performance disaster. However I don't see why the code doesn't work. Appart from terrible style, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Adami Yes, `[formatter release]` should go before the return.

Comment: NSNumber allocation should be done with param. Ramy is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to overwrite NSNumber?

For CustomNumber.h

```
@interface CustomNumber:NSNumber
-(NSString *) customFormatNumber:(float) n1;
```

For CustomNumber.m

```
-(NSString *) customFormatNumber:(float)n1
{
    NSLog(@" %f" ,n1); // for debug and a breakpoint here
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    NSString *nf = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:n1]];
    NSLog(@"Class %@" ,nf); // for debug
    [formatter release];
    return nf;
}
```

Then in MainViewController.m

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
CustomNumber *convertedNumber = [[CustomNumber alloc] init];
calculatorScreen.text = [convertedNumber customFormatNumber:currentNumber];
```

OR

In MainViewController.m create the method and then the code will be

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
calculatorScreen.text = [self customFormatNumber:currentNumber];
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it by the first method and I'll check the second :)

Answer (score 5):

`[[NSNumber alloc]init]` returns nil because you aren't specifying the number value, and nil targeted actions are ignored.

Let me tell you that you are following a long and unnecessary way, I would just write all this way:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter=[NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
calculatorScreen.text= [formatter stringFromNumber: @(currentNumber*10.0+[sender tag]) ];
```

Comment: Sorry? How do I have to specify that?

Comment: Something like @(yourFloafValue) or [NSNumber numberWithFloat: yourFloatValue];

Comment: But I think that you don't need to do that, just delete the category and use another approach.

Comment: That's good, for sure I'll take a look and try to simplify the code. Thanks!